# Removing double quotes returned by name manager/formula/cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use Name Manager to store absolute path to a file so I can reference them easily for VLOOKUP.

I'm sure the absolute path is correct because if I supplied the absolute path directly, it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1LfV.png).
It'll only fails if I use the variable name.

[Creating the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM9Ai.png)

The issue is when I want to use them for VLOOKUP, the reference shows the wrong results either by

1. [adding double quotes automatically to the file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2l0q.png)
2. [Showing the cell coordinates instead of the values on that position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t1sW.png)

What I've tried:

1. Using `INDIRECT` [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3LwE.png)
2. using `SUBSTITUTE` function
3. changing `Refers to` [changing refers to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFgBk.png)
4. Using `VALUETOTEXT` function

If using Name manager is not possible, please advice on how to store a file path that I can access and change its values easily.

Comment: Are you defining the defined name with or without double-quotes?

Comment: It is impossible to use `INDIRECT` function to the closed workbooks. Path in Excel should be given directly, not by text. You should use VBA. In VBA you can define cell's formula as text. You can adapt either of the solutions given here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838638/how-can-i-get-specific-cells-specific-worksheet-of-an-workbook-which-is-linked-a

Comment: @harrymc I'm defining the name with 2 single quotes. If I use only 1 single quote, it won't display any quote at the beginning.

And yes, I've tried with 1 single quote and 2 single quotes, I still can't achieve what I want

Comment: "Path in Excel should be given directly, not by text"  that really sucks if that is the case. Can you provide any sources that supports this claim?  Unfortunately, VBA is not allowed on the company i worked for so I can't use this suggestion.

Comment: From Microsoft documentation of `INDIRECT` function: "If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value."

Comment: You can read also this dicussion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408255/read-data-from-closed-xlsx-book-without-vba

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA, the only thing left is a roundabout way.

1. You can create the text of a working formula by assembling it from any elements (references to other cells, defined names, and text fragments).
2. Then copy the cell with this text to the clipboard (Ctrl+C).
3. Open the **Office clipboard** (it may have already been opened earlier).
   [image: Office Clipboard]
4. Copy the formula from the Office clipboard back into the cell.

Copying through the Office clipboard converts a formula to a value. In this case, the "value" is just the formula needed. It will immediately activate in the cell and return the result.
This method is effective, but it is not suitable for large-scale automation because each formula has to be manually copied.
But you can copy and paste several formulas at a time.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. Although not the solution I'm looking for, I appreciate you take the time to answer this ;)